# submit a form in rails and generate an html {#id}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

i have a form, i dont want to submit the form by ajax or jquery so that when submitted it adds generates an id to the url in the browser so when the page reloads it automatically scrowl's down to that id on the page

my form is

```
<%= form_for([activity, activity.talks.build],remote: true) do |f| %>
                    <%= f.text_field :details, :class=>"input-block-level", :placeholder=>"write a comment" %>

                <% end%> 

<ul id="chat">
          <%= render activity.talks %>
        </ul>
```

my create action for this form is

```
def create

    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    #@message = Message.create!(params[:message])
    @talk = @activity.talks.create!(talk_params)
    @talk.user = current_user
    @talk.save
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)

  end
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to scroll to a particular point in the page, you can make an html anchor and pass that as an option to the path-generator

eg try

```
redirect_to user_path(current_user, , :anchor => "user_#{current_user.id}")
```

But also make sure that you have:

```
<a name="user_<%= user.id %>"</a>
```

on the page for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand well, but shouldn't you first of all redirect to the talk_path instead of the user_path? since i assume you want to redirect to talk page. What Taryn said should work, just make the proper changes to link where you want. and i would definitely remove the

```
remote: true
```

from the form. with remote: true you won't get any redirect